# Symfony 2.7: How to change route in code?

Tags: symfony, url-routing

I have a website based on symfony. Routes are declared with yml-files. I use a 3rd-party extention, but wanted to change it's urls. I want to avoid changing the yml-files of this extention because they will be overwritten with the next update. Is there a way to change the route in my php-code instead of the yml-file?

Answer (score 2):

copy the routing file into your application and import it

from symfony doc

```
Routing is never automatically imported in Symfony. 
If you want to include the routes from any bundle, then they must be manually imported from somewhere in your application
(e.g. config/routes.yaml).




The easiest way to "override" a bundle's routing is to never import it at all. 
 Instead of importing a third-party bundle's routing, simply copy that routing file
into your application, modify it, and import it instead.
```

Comment: Thank you. What would be the way to make a route configurable then, like if the user checks something use route A, but if he unchecks it use route B?

Comment: @Werner maybe take a look at custom route loaders https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing/custom_route_loader.html